# None of the ciphers specified are supported by the SSL engine : TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I get following warning when started Tomcat with ssl debugging.

Feb 3, 2014 5:02:34 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory getEnableableCiphers
WARNING: None of the ciphers specified are supported by the SSL engine : TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256

I have setup bouncycastle as a crypto provider in java.security file and copied the jar to java_home/lib/ext

I have following in my connector configuration for HTTPS.

ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"

Java Version : 1.6

Due to this error - I also cannot connect to the server via browser too

Any help appreciated..

Comment: Have you solved it, if yes how?

Answer (score 2):

One solution to this problem was [posted here](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Problem-configuring-SSL-td5010128.html):

> I figured out what the problem was. 
>   It was not related to tomcat configuration, but to my keystore. The reason 
>   is that once you import a client certificate under the same alias as the 
>   private pair, they both get merged under the same alias inside keystore. 
>   Using keytool -delete command, meant to remove the certificate only, 
>   deletes the private pair as well. I noticed that once I dumped keystore 
>   content for my keystore and a keystore on one of my other servers. Luckily, 
>   I had a backup of the keystore I made right after it was created. Importing 
>   the certificates into that keystore resolved the issue.

Comment: I only have one key pair in my keystore. So I don't this is the issue. The issue seems to be due to the cipher I specify : TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256.